# How do I Visualize the cluster data in Python?

Tags: python, visualization

I have a set of cluster of words that I need to Visualize, how do I Visualize the data which has format as below.

```
[{'save', 'spare', 'write'}, {'stop', 'forget', 'stuff', 'blocked', 'block'}, {'service', 'serve', 'serving'}, {'history', 'story'}, {'worst', 'bad'}, {'accepted', 'recognized', 'spot'}, {'share', 'portion', 'fortune', 'part'}]
```

I am using python's platform.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Visualize" in this context. Could you describe what your result should sort of look like?

Comment: like a scatter plot or dendrogram?

Comment: `matplotlib` is a Python package that lets you do scatter plots and other visuals.  I was just trying to understand how, exactly, you intend to change words into plottable quantities.

Comment: I wanted to plot these words of same cluster in same colored points in scatter plot along with their text.